# Scaling the screen and components for other displays

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I'm trying to port my Swing program onto my laptop so I can develop, but I suppose the way I've written my component sizes makes it difficult for this to scale.

I decided to set the screen size using the `Toolkit.getScreenSize` method and derive the width/height integers to make a multipiler for the sizes, like so:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int width = screenSize.width;
int height = screenSize.height;
System.out.println(screenSize);
setSize(screenSize);
int matrixWidthModifier = (int) (width*.351523);
int matrixHeightModifer = (int) (height*0.625);
gamePanel.add(boardMatrixPanel, "wrap, align center, w "+ matrixWidthModifier+"!, h "+matrixHeightModifer+"!");
```

This doesn't produce my intended screen which looks something like this:

[image]

Instead, I get this:

[image]

However, I am using `.setPreferredSize` on a few components, but I'm not sure that they'd heavily impact the screen size. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do with `MigLayout`?

Comment: Use the pre-existing layouts, avoid `setPreferredSize` and consider using [`JFrame@setExtendedState`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int)) to maximise the window, it will give overall better results

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) sections.

Comment: @MadProgrammer would using sizing be acceptable when adding it to the layout or should I avoid defining sizes at all?

Comment: As a personal preference, I avoid it, preferring tings like insets ang gaps where supported by layouts, or borders